# Traefik Self Signed Certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik

I am trying to get one of my Docker containers to use a custom self-signed SSL. I have followed some instructions I have gathered from browsing around the internet and everything else works fine however my container keeps using a Traefik default certificate rather than the custom one I would like it to use. How can I achieve this?

To be honest, I am not exactly clear on how the Docker containers pick and use an SSL certificate and the documentation I have read does not seem to make it clear either. Here is what I have done so far.

**Docker Compose yml file for Traefik**

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ~/docker-data/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=insecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=api-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api-auth.basicauth.users=admin:..."
    container_name: traefik
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: "web"
```

**My Traefik yml file**

```
providers: # You can add more than one provider if needed
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    network: "web" # Custom docker network
    exposedByDefault: false # Only expose explicitly enabled containers

  file:
    filename: ~/docker-data/traefik/dynamic_conf.yml
    watch: true

entryPoints:
  insecure:
    address: ":80"
  secure:
    address: ":443"

api:
  dashboard: true
```

**My dynamic configuration file**

```
# Dynamic configuration
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: "~/ssl/bwtest-cert.pem"
      keyFile: "~/ssl/bwtest-key.pem"
```

**My Docker Container**

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  bwtest:
    image: bitwardenrs/server
    restart: always
    container_name: bwtest
    volumes:
      - bw-test-data:/data
#      - bw-test-ssl:/ssl
    environment:
      LOG_FILE: '/data/bw.log'
      SHOW_PASSWORD_HINT: 'true'
    labels:

      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-https.redirectScheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-https.redirectScheme.permanent=true
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-https.rule=Host(`bwtest.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-https.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-https.service=bwtest
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-http.rule=Host(`bwtest.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-http.entrypoints=insecure
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-http.middlewares=redirect-https
      - traefik.http.routers.bitwarden-ui-http.service=bwtest
      - traefik.http.services.bwtest.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.routers.mydomain.tls.domains[0].main=bwtest.com
      - traefik.http.routers.mydomain.tls.domains[0].sans=www.bwtest.com
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    external: true
volumes:
  bw-test-data:
  bw-test-ssl:
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever end up solving this? and if so how?

Comment: Hi, I did in the end thank you. This guide on generating self-signed certificates seemed to be the key - https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden/wiki/Private-CA-and-self-signed-certs-that-work-with-Chrome Traefik was then able to pick up my certificates.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest trying to move the certificates to default store (https://docs.traefik.io/https/tls/#default-certificate):

```
tls:
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: path/to/cert.crt
        keyFile: path/to/cert.key
```

Comment: What's the docker container label equivalent to this for those who wish to avoid additional files/mounts?